# Change action background color when selected (ActionBarSherlock)

Tags: android, background, actionbarsherlock

I want to change the color of the action background icon when it is pressed.

I tried the following but no results:

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item> -->
</style>

<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_item_background</item>
    <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/action_item_background</item>
</style>
```

**action_item_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>

</shape>
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution that I found was:

**action_item_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>

</shape>
```

**action_item_background_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" >

    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/action_item_background" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

</selector>
```

**styles.xml**

```
 <style name="Theme.Styled" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
            <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_item_background_selector</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_item_background_selector</item>
        </style>

        <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        //...
    </style>
```

Comment: This method should work in theory but my application is minSDKVersion 8 so it gives me this error: android:actionBarItemBackground requires API level 14 (current min is 8) And without this line, it is not working... Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a selector slector_action_item_background:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" >

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/action_item_background" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Then replace it in your style

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selector_action_item_background</item>
</style>
```