# How to change the background color of an icon in the action bar, when clicked?

Tags: android

The solution provided here doesnt work for me because it **requires api14 and I want to support earlier verions:**

[Change action background color when selected (ActionBarSherlock)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17263059/change-action-background-color-when-selected-actionbarsherlock)

Right now when I tap an item on the action bar with my finger it turns blue and I dont want that to happen.

Information:
I'm using SherlockActionBar.

and this doesnt work because it requires api11:

```
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
        icon.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
```

Here is my action_bar_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/abFeed"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_paste"
        android:title="@string/abFeed"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/abNotifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_social_cc_bcc"
        android:title="@string/abNotifications"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/abAddNewItem"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_content_new"
        android:title="@string/abAddNewItem"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/abSearch"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
        android:title="@string/abSearch"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

**EDIT: Here is what helped me solve the issue, thanks to Mario Lenci:**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@FF000000" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and in styles:xml

```
<style name="Theme.SherlockCustom" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_bar_item_background</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: how you are adding items in actionbar , through menu.xml??

Comment: yes, I will attach it to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to set this attribute in your application/Activity main Theme

```
<item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/your_drawable</item>
```

with action bar sherlok you also have to set

```
<item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/your_drawable</item>
```

you can find a good documentation on ActionBar styling [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style)

Comment: android:actionBarItemBackground requires API level 14 (current min is 10)

Comment: yeah i know, but you are using ActionBarSherlok to solve that problem.
So you define both the attribute( with and without android: ) and the right one will be loaded according to the device

Comment: but Im getting an xml red error underline and I cant run the project

Comment: just right click on the project -> android tools -> clear lint. I know that we should follow lint. but in this case it doesn't provoce any crash or something cause the "new" attribute will be just ignore when not supported

Comment: ok thank you for that! now problem is the color is always applied, not on click. How can I make that background change upon click only?

Comment: The raccomented solution would be to create a style.xml file in values-v14/ and define there the same theme with the attributes that are not supported before. In the other one you then leave the ActionBarSherlok ones in the other

Comment: You have to define a drawbale as selector ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList )

Comment: so how to I change this to make it work     <style name="Theme.SherlockCustom" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/action_bar_item_background</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    </style>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39116/discussion-between-mario-lenci-and-j-kowalski)